# Find $\dim (Ker T + ImT) $ and $\dim(Ker T \cap ImT) $

Tags: linear-algebra

let $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) $ be  a  basis  for  a vector space $V$ of dimension $4.$
  Define  a  linear transformation on $V$  such that  $T(x_1) = T(x_2) =T(x_3) = x_1$, and  $T(x_4) = x_2$.

Now  Find

$a) \dim (Ker T + ImT) $

$b) \dim(Ker T \cap ImT) $

my attempts :  First i convert  them into matrix $T =\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0& 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$

now here for  option $a)$  $\dim( Ker T) = 2, \dim (Im T)= 2$, so  $\dim (Ker T + ImT)= 4 $

For option $b)$ $$\dim (Ker T + ImT)=\dim( Ker T) +\dim (Im T) - \dim(Ker T \cap ImT)=  2- \dim(Ker T \cap ImT)$$   that  is $ 2 = 2 -\dim (Ker T \cap ImT)$

so,$\dim (Ker T \cap ImT) = 0$

Is  my  answer  is correct or not ????

pliz help me
thanks u

Comment: Your answers are not correct. The correct answer is $dim(Ker T +Im T)=3$ and $dim (Ker T \cap Im T)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to a matrix is a very good idea: if $A$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$, then you can substitute the image of $T$ with the column space $C(A)$ of $A$ and the kernel of $T$ with the null space $N(A)$ of $A$.

However, some computations are necessary, because you need to find either $C(A)+N(A)$ or $C(A)\cap N(A)$, in order to apply Grassmann’s formula.

The column space is spanned by
$$
\left\{\,
v_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\,\right\}
$$
The null space is spanned by
$$
\left\{\,
v_3=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
v_4=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\,\right\}
$$
The vector $v_3$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$; on the other hand, $\{v_1,v_2,v_4\}$ is linearly independent. Therefore
$$
\dim(C(A)+N(A))=3
$$
Now Grassmann’s formula says
$$
\dim(C(A)\cap N(A))=\dim C(A)+\dim N(A)-\dim(C(A)+N(A))=2+2-3=1
$$

Since $C(A)\cap N(A)$ contains $v_3$ and has dimension $1$, so we conclude that $C(A)\cap N(A)$ is spanned by $v_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, you may not have necessary $dim(\ker T + \mathrm{im} T) \ne dim(\ker T) + \dim(\mathrm{im} T)$, because $\ker T$ and $\mathrm{im} t$ may intersect on more than $\{0\}$.

So find $\ker T$, by solving $T(\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2 + \alpha_3x_3 + \alpha_4x_4) = (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3) x_1 + \alpha_4 x_2 = 0$.  I.e, you must have
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = 0\\
\alpha_4 = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Likewise, find $\mathrm{im} T$ (easy enough).

Then compute their sum $\ker T + \mathrm{im} T$ by using two generating two sequences of each and reducing it to a base of the sum by iteratively removing vector that can be expressed as a linear combination of others.  How many vectors are you left with ?